# How to configure F# JSON type provider to use UTF-8 for POST requests?

Tags: json, encoding, f#, fsharp.data.typeproviders

I need to encode as UTF-8 HTTP payloads sent using F# JSON type provider JsonValue.Request method.

The Request allows specifying HTTP headers but JSON type provider takes care of setting Content-Type header as "application/json" without specifying "charset" qualifier. If I try to set content type myself I end up with duplicate header value (causing an error indeed). And with only "application/json" the following code selects defauls encoding:

```
let getEncoding contentType =
    let charset = charsetRegex.Match(contentType)
    if charset.Success then
        Encoding.GetEncoding charset.Groups.[1].Value
    else
        HttpEncodings.PostDefaultEncoding
```

PostDefaultEncoding is is ISO-8859-1 which is not suitable in our scenario.

Any idea how PostDefaultEncoding can be overridden for JsonValue.Request payload?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the `JsonValue.Request` method is just a convenient helper that covers the most common scenarios, but does not necessarily give you all the power you need for making arbitrary requests. (That said, UTF-8 sounds like a more reasonable default.)

The most general F# Data function is `Http.Request`, which lets you upload data in any way:

```
let buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes ""
Http.RequestString
  ( "https://httpbin.org/post", 
    httpMethod="POST", 
    body=HttpRequestBody.BinaryUpload buffer )
```

So, if you replace `""` with `yourJsonValue.ToString()`, this should send the request with UTF-8 encoded body.

Comment: Thank you Tomas, using Http.Request would definitely solve it. I used Http.fs instead but with your suggestion I could achieve everything with just one library. But it would be nice to slightly improve JsonValue.Request because it would eliminate the need for all this ceremony around obtaining a string buffer, specifying HTTP request body etc. One way to do this is to respect Content-Encoding header. Once it's specified it could choose payload encoding overriding default ISO-8859-1.